# PFQuery from an array in order SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I want to use parse PFQuery to query from an array of objects, but I want the outcome to be in the order that I have put it in, so for example:

```
var age = [26, 28, 30, 20]

var ageQuery = PFUser.query()
ageQuery.whereKey("age", containedIn: age)

  let finalResult = ageQuery.findObjects()

  println(finalResult) // To equal my search but in the order I have put them in, so the first result should be 26, then 28 etc.
```

Is there a certain where of searching by in the order they are put in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. The documentation certainly doesn't promise anything about the order of the results.

Your best option is to sort the results once you have received them. Consider using `sortedArrayUsingComparator` and for each object that you're comparing find its index in the source array and use the indexes to decide the resulting `NSComparisonResult`.

In swift it seems you can shortcut a little, so something along the lines of:

```
var sortedResult = sorted(finalResult) { (obj1, obj2) in

    let p1 = obj1 as Person
    let p2 = obj2 as Person

    let index1 = find(age, p1.age)!
    let index2 = find(age, p2.age)!

    return index1 < index2
}
```

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks. Could you expand at all of how this might be done more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ascending()` or `descending()`.

For example if your query is called `query`, `query.orderByAscending("parameter you want to sort")` will sort the results for you.

Note that the methods only take in strings/string variables.

This allows you to sort by a parameter that exists on your Parse database.

For example, say you want to order the "username" field from the `User` class (and you are already using `query` to retrieve the `User` class. `query.orderByAscending("username")` will sort alphabetically for you.

Comment: But how does this help me with my question above? I can only do `orderByAscending` by Parses database, not by my `age` array. I don't want it to be in Ascending or descending order I want it to be in a very specific order that it is put into the array.